# How to call buzzer sound of device on windows embedded 7?

Tags: windows-mobile, windows-ce, windows-mobile-6.5

My device does not support the WAV or MP3 file formats. I want to play a buzzer sound on my Windows Embedded 7 system. Is it possible to achieve this using C++ or C#?
Can anyone suggest how to proceed with this?
i new programmer for windows ce help me pls.
Thank you.

Comment: Does the device have a speaker? Does it play any sound when it boots or if there is an error?

Answer (score 0):

If the device is able to play system sounds you may use this API:

```
 using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
 [DllImport("coredll.dll")]
 internal static extern void MessageBeep(MB type);
 internal enum MB
 {
   ICONHAND = 0x00000010,
   ICONQUESTION  = 0x00000020,
   ICONEXCLAMATION = 0x00000030,
   ICONASTERISK = 0x00000040,
 }
```

The code is already wrapped for C#. You then call a beep using

```
 MessageBeep(MB.ICONHAND);
```

Let us know, if that works for you.